# Can change shape of range with ARRAYFORMULA() in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

My intention is to convert a single line of data into rows consist of a specific number of columns in Google Sheets.

For example, starting with the raw data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id1 | attr1-1 | attr2-1 | id2 | attr2-1 | attr2-2 |

And the expected result is:
(by dividing columns by three)

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id1 | attr1-1 | attr1-2 |
| 2 | id2 | attr2-1 | attr2-2 |

I already know that it's possible a bit manually, like:
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:C1;D1:F1})

But I have to start over with it every time the target range is moved OR the subset size needs to be changed (in the case above it was three)!

So I guess there will be a much more graceful way (i.e. formula does not require manual update) to do the same thing and suspect ARRAYFORMULA() is the key.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Much is still unclear, both about your real-world application and even the details of your post example. For instance, you say that you want a formula that doesn't require manual updates. But how your existing formula "know" that it should break the example data into 3 columns instead of 2 (or 6) unless you manually enter that information somewhere? Will the raw data always be in only one row? Is there some "rule" that should be applied to ranges of any and all sizes? To what different scenarios will the formula need to adapt? It always helps to know the real-world application goal.

Comment: More: What does "every time the target range is moved" mean? How would it move? Why?

Comment: @ErikTyler Thank you so much for the comment and advice!
1. By saying "no manual update" I meant that I want to avoid changing reference range {A1:C1;D1:F1} into {A1:D1;E1:G1} in case number of columns increased. (Instead just wondered if it's possible to put 3 or 4 as argument in the formula.)

Comment: 2. As illustrated in the updated example, raw data is pairs of id + attributes. Though example contains only a couple of it but the total number of attributes are not fixed, and there's no separators can be used with split(). Anyway, data will be always in a single row and can be expanded horizontally (depends on the number of records fetched dynamically using importXML() function).
I guess this explanation addresses other questions you have posted!

Comment: You've provided more information, which is helpful. But it is still not 100% clear. Is it possible that ID1 will have 1 attribute, but ID2 will have 3 attributes and ID3 will have 2 attributes, etc., all in the same row? Or will any one row always have an ID followed be a set number of attributes? What does your REAL data look like? Are you going to be trying to process multiple rows? If so, will all rows have the same number of attributes per ID, or will that change per row? Where will the results go—same sheet or another sheet? You see that many questions remain, and they are all important.

Comment: The most efficient and effective way to receive help is to share a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it, or a mock version of it that contains realistic data enough to convey the issue), being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." That way, we can see for ourselves what the data and layout really look like.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Erik, Thought I have posted my own answer below, to clarify myself: I have decided not to show the real data here because the major part is non-US characters which might confuse others trying to help. Thanks so much once again!

Comment: Yes, SEQUENCE was the most likely approach. Now that I can see an example sheet and data, what you are trying to do can be done in one formula and by setting only one parameter instead of two. Your sheet is currently set to "View only." If you'd like to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor," I'll share my recommended (and simpler) approach with you on the sheet.

Comment: Hey @ErikTyler, checked what you have added to the sample sheet I made. As a show of gratitude, I would like to accept your answer if you care to post one. Thanks!

Comment: Posted. Thanks. And enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a new sheet ("Erik Help") where I reduced your manually entered parameters from two to one (leaving only # of columns to be entered in `A2`).

The formula that reshapes the grid:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(7:7)/A2),A2),{SEQUENCE(COUNTA(7:7),1),FLATTEN(FILTER(7:7,7:7<>""))},2,FALSE)))`

`SEQUENCE` is used to shape the grid according to whatever is entered in `A2`. Rows would be the count of items in Row 7 divided by the number in `A2` (rounded to the nearest whole number); and the columns would just be whatever number is entered in `A2`.

Example: If there are 11 items in Row 7 and you want 4 columns, ROUNDUP(11/4)=3 rows to the SEQUENCE and your requested 4 columns.

Then, each of those numbers in the grid is `VLOOKUP`'ed in a virtual array consisting of a vertical SEQUENCE of ordered numbers matching the number of data pieces in Row 7 (in Column 1) and a `FLATTEN`ed (vertical) version of the Row-7 data pieces themselves (in Column 2). Matches are filled into the original SEQUENCE grid, while non-matches are left blank by `IFERROR`

Answer (score 0):

Though it's a bit messy, managed to get it done thanks to SEQUENCE() function anyway.
It constructs a grid by accepting number of rows/columns input, and that was exactly I was looking for.

For reference set up a sheet with the sample data here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p972tYlsPvC6nM39qLNjYRZZWGZYsUnGaA7kXyfJ8F4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a custom formula

Although you already solved this. If you are doing this kind of thing a lot, it could be beneficial to look into Apps Script and custom formulas.

In this case you could use something like:

```js
function transposeSingleRow(range, size) {
  // initialize new range
  let newRange = []
  // initialize counter to keep track
  let count = 0;
  // start while loop to go through row (range[0])
  while (count < range[0].length){
    // add a slice of the original range to the new range
    newRange.push(
      range[0].slice(count, count + size)
      );
    // increment counter
    count += size;
  }
  return newRange;
}
```

Which works like this:

[image]

The nice thing about the formula here is that you select the range, and then you put in a number to represent its throw, or how many elements make up a complete row. So if instead of 3 attributes you had 4, instead of calling:

```
=transposeSingleRow(A7:L7, 3)
```

you could do:

```
=transposeSingleRow(A7:L7, 4)
```

Additionally, if you want this conversion to be permanent and not dependent on formula recalculation. Making it in run fully in Apps Script without using formulas would be neccesary.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Thanks so much for the code and the example either! I will definitely consider using it on my future projects, while I would rather stick to a formula-based solution for this instance because it has to be used across multiple sheets. (Yeah, I am aware that custom formula also can be published as a library but it's enough for now.)